# Overloading/Specializing Method Of A Templated Class

Tags: c++, templates

I want a templated class that has two methods with the same name: One that takes a parameter of type T& and the other that takes Rational& as parameter where Rational is my class.
I'm not sure whether this is called template specialization or just simple overloading
One other thing is that I don't have an h and cpp file but an hpp file which contains the declaration with the implementation.

What would be the correct sytanx for this?

Somthing like this:

```
template <class T> class Matrix
{

    bool hasTrace (Rational& trace) const
    {
    }

    bool hasTrace (T& trace) const
    {
    }
}
```

Only this code doesn't compile and I get the compilation error:

```
..\/Matrix.hpp:200:7: error: 'bool Matrix<T>::hasTrace(T&) const [with T = Rational]' cannot be overloaded
..\/Matrix.hpp:180:7: error: with 'bool Matrix<T>::hasTrace(Rational&) const [with T = Rational]'
```

I now looked at this tutorial: 
[enter link description here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/144-expression-parameters-and-template-specialization/)

Under Template specialization, it says that what I want to accomplish can be done by defining the specialized function outside of the class definition while replacing the template type with the specific type I wish to redefine the function for:

```
bool Matrix<Rational>::hasTrace (Rational& trace) const
{
}
```

but now I get this error:

```
..\/Matrix.hpp:227:6: error: specializing member 'Matrix<Rational>::hasTrace' requires 'template<>' syntax
```

Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is indeed to define the specialized method outside the class like this:

```
template <> bool Matrix<Rational>::hasTrace (Rational& trace) const
{
}
```

The reason that didn't compile at first was that I have implementation in this file which is an hpp file (I know it's really bad but this is an exercise and this is the only option we were given).
Than, to add insult to injury I included this file in two cpp files at which point I got the error:

```
multiple definition of `Matrix<Rational>::hasTrace(Rational&) const'
```

@DanielFrey, thanks anyway for trying to help me!

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable the second overload if `T` is `Rational`. With C++, you'd use a specialization:

```
template <class T> class Matrix
{
    bool hasTrace (Rational& trace) const
    {
    }

    bool hasTrace (T& trace) const
    {
    }
};

template<> class Matrix< Rational >
{
    bool hasTrace (Rational& trace) const
    {
    }
};
```

With C++11, you could also use `std::enable_if`:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class T> class Matrix
{
    bool hasTrace (Rational& trace) const
    {
    }

    typename std::enable_if< !std::is_same< T, Rational >::value, bool >::type
    hasTrace (T& trace) const
    {
    }
};
```

(or you could use Boost's type traits to achieve the same in C++98)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Regarding your first suggestion, I have other methods in this class. will I need to copy those other methods to the specialized class even though it's the same implementation?

Comment: @OrBarya: Basically yes, which is why I prefer and recommend the second method. You could also move common methods to a base class or try other techniques, but the `enable_if` version is the most local fix for your problem.

Comment: Sorry to bother you but I updated my post with another option, Please look at it if you can.